# How can I read a .xz file in Python?

Tags: python, xz, jsonstream

I am downloading files from the web with the ending .xz.
It says they are JSONstrean files.

Is there a way to read these files in Python, for example like a CSV file?

Answer (score 3):

Python has a library [lzma](https://docs.python.org/3/library/lzma.html) for Reading and writing compressed files

Here is a simple running code

```
import lzma
with lzma.open('filename.xz', mode='rt') as file:
    for line in file:
       print(line)
```